# v-on:click is not working for a button on simple Vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is a basic vue.js project where I have added a button on the page. When the button is clicked, the *showProduct* property is set to either *true* or *false*.
The html part is as below

```
    <div id="app">
        <button v-on:click="showCheckout">Click Me</button>
    </div>
```

The Vue object is as follows

```
    <script>
        const store = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            showProduct:true,
        },
    
        methods: {
            showCheckout: function() {
                this.showProduct = this.showProduct ? false: true;
            }
        }
        });
    </script>
```

**Problem:** The property is not updated when the button is clicked. I have tried to use `return this.showProduct = this.showProduct ? false: true;` but the issue remained unsolved.

If I open the Vue dev tools and in the Components tab I click the *Root* component the value changes once. If the button is clicked again several times the value does not change. It only changes when I first click the button on the page and then click the *Root* component in dev tools. If the root *Root* component is clicked twice, the value does not change.

Comment: It works perfectly on my side.

Comment: @Derlin I tried clearing out the browser cache. Restarted the browser but the issue still remained there. When I viewed the _showedProduct_ in chrome console, the property was changing but the **Root** component of my application was not updating the property.
When the **Root** component is clicked from Vue dev tools the value is changed once

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine. You can run this code snippet here as well to verify

```js
const store = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            showProduct:true,
        },
    
        methods: {
            showCheckout: function() {
                this.showProduct = this.showProduct ? false: true;
            }
        }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="showCheckout">Click Me</button>
  {{showProduct}}
</div>
```

Comment: The showProduct attribute is not changing inside the data object of "Root". According to the book, the attribute toggles the true and false values within the "Root" component's data object

Comment: Please open the Vue dev tools and inspect the _showProduct_ property of **Root** component. It is not updated. 
The updated is visible on the chrome console but not in the Vue dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need a method for single assignment. See below snippet

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      showProduct: false
    }
  }
})
```

```html
   

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
 <div id="app">
    <h1 v-if="showProduct" > My product </h1>
    <button v-on:click="showProduct = !showProduct">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with the way how Vuejs works. The book suggests that you can use a method for single assignment. You can find this in the book **Vue.js in Action** page number 75. I am looking for a way to toggle the property without using data function